# GGTS editor tooltip show itself too fast

Tags: grails, groovy, tooltip, spring-tool-suite

I am using GGTS on WIN7 64bit to edit my Grails project.
When editing GSP or groovy, once I point my mouse to something in the source code, a tooltip will show itself in less than 1ms. This is very annoying.

What I really wanna do is to click that source code and start to type something in that position. Because of the too-fast showing of tooltip, my click will drop on that tooltip and breaks my thoughts.

Can anyone help to set the tooltip to show itself after 500ms of mouse pointing at the same position? Thanks.

I didn't find this configuration from Windows->Preference of my GGTS 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Eclipse to show hovers only when you really want them.
For controlling the hovers behavior for the GSP editor:

- Go To **Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > Structured Text Editors**
- Switch to the Hovers tab
- Choose "Combined Hover"
- Add a "Pressed key modifier while hovering"

This will cause the hovers to appear only when you press this specific key combination and hover over the text.

The same can be done for other editor types.